# How to turn ON the jsTree contextmenu only for the nodes that are beyond level 2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

So my issue is that i need have contextmenu only on the nodes of my tree that are nested after the 2nd level or deeper. For example :

[image]

I want to have the default context menu on the nodes "1.1.1", "1.1.1.1", etc... but i dont want this context menu to appear when i right-click on "1" or "1.1".

How i'm supposed to choose on which nodes to appear and on which not ?

I found some examples like this one :

```
function customMenu(node) {
   //Show a different label for renaming files and folders
   if ($(node).hasClass("jstree-closed") || $(node).hasClass("jstree-open")) { //If node is a folder
      var renameLabel = "Rename Folder";
   }
   else {
      var renameLabel = "Rename File";
   }
   var items = {
      "upload" : {
          "label" : "Upload File",
          "action" : function () { ... }
      },
      "rename" : {
         "label" : renameLabel,   //Different label (defined above) will be shown depending on node type
         "action" : function () { ... }
      },
      "delete" : {
         "label" : "Delete File",
         "action" : function () { ... }
      }
   };

   //If node is a folder do not show the "delete" menu item
   if ($(node).hasClass("jstree-closed") || $(node).hasClass("jstree-open")) {
      delete items.remove;
   }

   return items;
}
```

I need something like this, but i dont know how to check on which level my folder is nested. The checks in my example are for "folder or file".

Has anyone a clue ?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think jsTree has a out-of-the-box method for it, so you can suppress the menu showing up for nodes at level 1 and 2 with the code as below. Check demo - [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/vfzmcofa/).

```
.on('show_contextmenu.jstree', function(e, reference, element) {

    if ( reference.node.parents.length < 3 ) {
        $('.vakata-context').remove();
    }

});
```